# iOS, leftButtonItem 'are you sure?' approach to confirming exit from screen approach?

Tags: ios, user-interface, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to figure out the standard approach or the best approach.

I don't want my users (children) to accidentally tap the back button and lose what they have entered into a view.

1) In a very old implementation, there's a `leftBarButtonItem` with an action which shows an alert asking `are you sure`. But I can't do this without losing the arrow provided by the back button and I don't want to add my own < image.

I've looked into the back button solution of a variable where you keep track of other routes out of the view, then do something in `viewDidDisappear`, but I won't be able to show an alert and cancel here.

2) I could have my own buttons and not have a navigation bar at all, but the buttons aren't going to look normal.

What;s the standard approach to solve this?

Comment: IS far as I'm aware, there is no strait approach override standard back-button without unstable hacks. However you can retain controller and show it again.

Comment: Not sure if this exactly what you meant, but I could always save data  then I don’t need the ‘are you sure’

Comment: You can save data, or you can save what controller to push (with prefilled fields), and present it. Saving data definitely more effective, because it ca cover other cases such as switching to other apps, crashes, etc,

Comment: Not sure that someone can press back button at the top left by accident. That's why it's there! (Android definitely has this issue) As guys mention above saving data is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to change the action of the back button. This does include presenting alerts and other UI elements that delay or cancel the back action.

What you can do, is present the controller modally and instead of a back button use a different glyph, such as a cross. Then present an alert when the user taps the button (eg snapchat on creating a snapsterpieces)